# Translate a coordinate to maintain proportion when the canvas is resizing in WPF for VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am making a Image manipulation tool in WPF (VB.Net)

I have implemented Image translation and zooming in Image control by using Image RenderTransform.

Actually, the `Image` is inside the `Canvas` control like a *Photoshop Canvas*.
And there is an `Image` within that `Canvas` control like a *Layer in Photoshop*.

What I want to do is when **I resize the outer `Canvas` control, the `Image` inside should also be resized and repositioned as the outer control is**.
It means, the Image should get 'new width, new height, new x(or offset-x or left), new y(or offset-y, or top)'

But so far as I know, surprisingly, `RenderTransform` does not actually change the `Image` location and size!
Which means, assume there is a photo of 10x20. If I enlarged the image twice then it looks like 20x40. But the properties of Width, ActualWidth, RenderedSize.Width all of them shows 10x20-the original size.

Moreover, although I pan(translate or relocate) the `Image` within the `Canvas`, the Left(or Canvas.Left) does not change at all!

---

In summary,

1. `Image` control within a `Canvas` control design
2. Move `Image` inside the `Canvas` with mouse - done by `RenderTransform`
3. Resize "`Image`(not `Canvas`)" inside the `Canvas` - performed by `ScaleAtPrepend` and `RenderTransform` too.

> 4. Resize the outer `Canvas` -> and it should encompasses the inside `Image` to be resized *(like s to 1.5s in the figure)* with the same
>      ratio of outer `Canvas` is, and the Left and Top (or offset x,y) of
>      the Image to be translated(or relocated) according to the proper
>      variable *(like x,y to 1.5x,1.5y in the figure)*.

Unfortunately, using the zoom coefficient like '1.5' seems to be not viable because the original (x,y) point is alway (0,0) because the RenderTransform does not change the location values themselves.

Where can I start? How can I make it work?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Helping Image]

Here is a XAML design.

```
        <Canvas x:Name="CanvasBoard"  ClipToBounds="True"  Background="#FFC1C1C1" >

            <Image x:Name="CanvasImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDown_Click" MouseMove="MouseMove_Click" MouseLeftButtonUp="MouseLeftButtonUp_Click" GotFocus="ImageGotFocus" />

        </Canvas>
```

Panning with mouse core code.

```
Dim lsPoint = e.GetPosition(CanvasBorder)
Dim res As Point = lsPoint - firstPoint

Dim transform As MatrixTransform = CType(sender, Image).RenderTransform
Dim matrix = transform.Matrix
matrix.TranslatePrepend(res.X, res.Y)

CanvasImage.RenderTransform = New MatrixTransform(matrix)
```

Comment: Have you tried this with `LayoutTransform` instead?

Comment: @MarkFeldman actually yes. But the main point is to calculate the coordination after the resizing.

Comment: Using GeometryDrawing seems to provide easier manipulation.